# Extracting values which contains strings from [A-Z]

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract those values which is having strings fro [A-Z] (they may  include numbers also) from the vector dynamically,with out specifying them in "str"

My code is as below:

```
strings <- c("1", "70.5", "sh", "av", "3", "12","as","da","da","azz1")
     str <- c("sh", "av","as","da","azz1")
    matches <- unique (grep(paste(str,collapse="|"), 
                            strings, value=TRUE))
```

Comment: Did you meant `grep("^[a-z]+$", strings, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Don't call an object `str`; it's a built-in function (`str()`) for structure

Comment: yes exactly..but how to include both Upper case / mixed in the above statemant like strings <- c("1", "70.5", "sh", "aV", "3", "12","as","da","da","azz1","DA")

Comment: Use `tolower(strings)`

Comment: Do you mean strictly the 26 characters in the latin alphabet, or does it include modified characters with accents? Or do you want it to depend on the user's locale setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
> unique(grep("^[a-zA-Z]", strings, value = TRUE))
[1] "sh"   "av"   "as"   "da"   "azz1"
```

Which should allow you to have strings starting with both lower and upper case characters. Another example with upper case characters:

```
> strings2 <- c("1", "70.5", "sh", "aV", "3", "12","as","da","da","azz1","DA")
> unique(grep("^[a-zA-Z]", strings2, value = TRUE))
[1] "sh"   "aV"   "as"   "da"   "azz1" "DA"
```

Comment: for the regex: the more compact `grep("^[A-z]+", strings, value = TRUE)` will do

Comment: Again NO! `"^[a-zA-Z]+"` - that matches things that start with letters but might have anything else after the first letter: `grep("^[a-zA-Z]+","a&b", value=TRUE)` for example. Use `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` if what the user wants is a sequence of alphanumerics only. Its not clear in the question even.

Comment: I have edited again, from the question it seems OP wouldn't want `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` given his example in `str` which includes no strings beginning with a number.